# My code pops open a new blank tab, but only when used in Google Sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code. Keep in mind, the problem only arises when used inside an HTML box in Google Sites. It works perfectly in I.E and Chrome when saved to an HTML file. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why when inside Google Sites, it opens a new tab with no data. The code still works when you close the extra tab.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
session_start();
print "
<html>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#body {
  display:none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<font size=+5><b>Why would we make a refund and what is the process?</b></font><br>
<div id="body1"><br><br>
  <div>
  <a href='#' class='articleTitle'><font size="+1"><b>The first thing is the circumstances Under which we would make a refund. There are 2 reasons:</b></font></a>
  <div class='showArticle'>
    <p>1. The first reason for a refund would be an Ebay job that we are unable to complete for whatever reason.<br>
     2. The other reason for a refund would be as resolution of a warranty.
  </div>
  </div>
<div id="body2">
  <div>
  <a href='#' class='articleTitle'><font size="+1"><b>How do we process a refund?</b></font></a>
  <div class='showArticle'>
    <p>1. To process a refund for an Ebay job, follow <a href="https://docs.google.com/a/helpscore.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=aGVscHNjb3JlLmNvbXxraG9hdGVzdHxneDo1NTgyZTA4OTk0YzM3MzU0"><b>instructions</b></a> to be sure all steps are being followed correctly, then send an email to have the refund processed.<br>
    2. In the case of a refund as part of the <a href="https://docs.google.com/a/helpscore.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=aGVscHNjb3JlLmNvbXxraG9hdGVzdHxneDozOWEyZWMwZjBjYzVlYzg5"><b>Warranty Process</b></a>, you must have the customer's agreement and forward that to the refund email address.<br><br>
  </div>
  </div>
<div id="body3">
  <div>
  <a href='#' class='articleTitle'><font size="+1"><b>What is the refund email address and email content?</b></font></a>
  <div class='showArticle'>
    <p>When requesting a refund, please forward the customer's refund acceptance and change the subject to: <b>"Please refund customer $"</b><br>
  Please be sure to use the correct <a href="https://docs.google.com/a/helpscore.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=aGVscHNjb3JlLmNvbXxraG9hdGVzdHxneDo1ZThiZjdkNWZiZGIwOWZl"><b>Template</b></a>. You will have to download the file to access it correctly.<br>
  Here is the note to leave after you have sent the refund request: Refund Request sent<br>
  The email address to send the request to is: PSrefunds@porch.com
  </div>
  </div>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.showArticle').hide();
$('.articleTitle').show();

$('.showComments').hide();
$('.commentTitle').show();

$('.articleTitle').click(function(){
$(this).next('.showArticle').slideToggle();
});

$('.commentTitle').click(function(){
$(this).next('.showComments').slideToggle();

});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the issue may be here in the JQuery?

{send:function(c,d){var e,f=a.xhr(),g=++Bb;if(f.open(a.type,a.url,a.async,a.username,a.password),

With the jquery hosted outside, how do I fix this?

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You may fix this by adding event.preventDefault().
Like:

```
$('.articleTitle').click(function(e){
$(this).next('.showArticle').slideToggle();
e.preventDefault();
});

$('.commentTitle').click(function(e){
$(this).next('.showComments').slideToggle();
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now that I see it, it seems obvious. Thank you